# docker on windows not working

Tags: virtualbox, docker, boot2docker

I have tried installing docker on windows 7 (using boot2docker).
However the console just exists abruptly and I am unable to see the error, much less run any commands.

In the installation I have tried both installing and not installing the VirtualBox.
I have also tried un-installing and re-installing both docker and virtualbox. Nothing seems to work.

Here are the console errors I see when I run `boot2docker -v up`:

```
Boot2Docker-cli version: v1.3.0
Git commit: deafc19
2014/10/26 20:47:11 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe showvminfo boot2docker-vm --machinereadable
2014/10/26 20:47:12 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe guestproperty set boot2docker-vm /VirtualBox/GuestAdd/SharedFolders/MountPrefix /
2014/10/26 20:47:12 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe guestproperty set boot2docker-vm /VirtualBox/GuestAdd/SharedFolders/MountDir /
2014/10/26 20:47:12 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe sharedfolder add boot2docker-vm --name c/Users --hostpath C:\Users --automount
VBoxManage.exe: error: Shared folder named 'c/Users' already exists
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_IN_USE (0x80bb000c), component SessionMachine, interface IMachine, callee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "CreateSharedFolder(Bstr(name).raw(), Bstr(hostpath).raw(), fWritable, fAutoMount)" at line 1009 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
2014/10/26 20:47:12 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe setextradata boot2docker-vm VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/c/Users 1
2014/10/26 20:47:12 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe startvm boot2docker-vm --type headless
Waiting for VM "boot2docker-vm" to power on...
VBoxManage.exe: error: VT-x is disabled in the BIOS. (VERR_VMX_MSR_VMXON_DISABLED)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component Console, interface IConsole
2014/10/26 20:47:15 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe showvminfo boot2docker-vm --machinereadable
error in run: Failed to start machine "boot2docker-vm": exit status 1
```

Comment: Could you check your BIOS to see if there is a setting for VT-x? VBoxManage.exe: error: VT-x is disabled in the BIOS. (VERR_VMX_MSR_VMXON_DISABLED)

Comment: It worked, thanks :)
If you add this as an answer I'll accept it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check your BIOS for a VT-x setting. According to the log you provided, there is an error: `VBoxManage.exe: error: VT-x is disabled in the BIOS. (VERR_VMX_MSR_VMXON_DISABLED)`

Answer (score 0):

As sangil said, the error was in your BIOS.This afternoon my laptop splash same error about VT-x dissabled on Bios