# boot2docker starting in Windows 7

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I am having issues to start boot2docker in windows 7, virtualbox 4.3.26 (installed together with boot2docker).

Here is the output

```
Boot2Docker-cli version: v1.6.0
Git commit: 9894ae9
2015/05/05 17:08:12 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe showvminfo boot2docker-vm --machinereadable
2015/05/05 17:08:12 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe guestproperty set boot2docker-vm /VirtualBox/GuestAdd/SharedFolders/MountPrefix /
2015/05/05 17:08:12 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe guestproperty set boot2docker-vm /VirtualBox/GuestAdd/SharedFolders/MountDir /
2015/05/05 17:08:12 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe sharedfolder add boot2docker-vm --name c/Users --hostpath C:\Users --automount
VBoxManage.exe: error: Shared folder named 'c/Users' already exists
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_IN_USE (0x80bb000c), component SessionMachine, interface IMachine, callee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "CreateSharedFolder(Bstr(name).raw(), Bstr(hostpath).raw(), fWritable, fAutoMount)" at line 1008 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
2015/05/05 17:08:12 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe setextradata boot2docker-vm VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/c/Users 1
2015/05/05 17:08:12 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe startvm boot2docker-vm --type headless
Waiting for VM "boot2docker-vm" to power on...
VM "boot2docker-vm" has been successfully started.
2015/05/05 17:08:16 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe showvminfo boot2docker-vm --machinereadable
Waiting for VM and Docker daemon to start...
.Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connect
ing to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to t
cp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://loc
alhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2
022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (att
empt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0)
.Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connect
ing to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to t
cp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://loc
alhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2
022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (att
empt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0)
.Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connect
ing to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to t
cp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://loc
alhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2
022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (att
empt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0)VM Host-only IP address:
Waiting for Docker daemon to start...
o2015/05/05 17:09:53 executing: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\ssh.exe ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o LogLevel=quiet -p 2022 -i C:\Users\zencv\.ssh\id_boot2docker docker@localhost grep tcp:// /proc/$(cat /var/run/docker.pid)/cmdline
```

Then it hangs..

My virtualbox config is as follows (sorry, in german):

[image]

I tried different things such as deleting the boot2docker-vm, downloading again and starting again and again.
Also please note that this seems to be different from similar issues like [Boot2Docker Start up fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27544622/boot2docker-start-up-fails) or [docker on windows not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26587945/docker-on-windows-not-working) -- in those cases, the error message explicitly mentions that the virtualization is disabled, but I do not see any such error in my output. Unfortunately, I work in a very controlled env. and I cannot use any tools that check whether virtualization is enabled or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [similar boot2docker issue](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/625) mentions:

> It sounds like you might have a stray boot2docker-vm set up in VirtualBox -- it's probably worth trying to open the VirtualBox GUI to delete that and try:

```
boot2docker -v init 
boot2docker -v up
```

The complete reinstall process is:

```
docker cask remove virtualbox
docker cask install virtualbox
boot2docker delete
boot2docker init
boot2docker up
```

Also check if you have a `%HOME%` environment variable defined:

> The problem was my SSH Config. When it try to connect to boot2docker vm, it use my github private key and not the boot2docker private key.
>
> I confirm it works perfectly. Just changing `%HOME%/.ssh/config`
> I added:

```
Host boot2docker
  Hostname localhost
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_boot2docker
```

Comment: %HOME%/.ssh/config is missing completely for me, I will try your suggestion. Another thing to mention is that in my etc/hosts, the line ' `localhost 127.0.0.1` is commented out though I can ping localhost and I get reply from 127.0.0.1. I have seen some blog posts suggesting to uncomment that line, but I cannot understand why that would help when I can ping localhost

Comment: @zencv I would focus first on the value of `%HOME%` and the existence of `%HOME%\.ssh\config` indeed.