# unable to run boot2docker-vm in windows

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, virtualbox, boot2docker

I am having issues with Boot2Docker for Windows in windows 7. When I run the "start.sh" script for starting Boot2Docker, after initializing the boot2docker-vm, starting the vm fails.

[image: vm start fails]

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing. It did not help. I have deleted the boot2docker-vm and tried which also did not help. When I open Oracle VM VirtualBox manager, it is showing the VM "boot2docker-vm" with state Powered-Off and I could not start VM from there as well.

[image: info]

Any help on how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try and use boot2docker with a regular account instead of the Administrator one.
And make sure to use for now a VirtualBox 4.3.x, not the latest 5.0

As illustrated by [issue 600](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/600), it relies on a "standard" %USERPROFILE% (`C:\Users\aUser`)

A `boot2docker start -v` can add more information on the exact root cause.

Comment: @Rajmohan `--name c/Users --hostpath C:\Users` seems strange. Try using a regular account, not an Admin windows session

Comment: I had boot2docker working till yesterday. Dont know what happened today after I shutdown and started the pc again. I only have single account in my pc. Ok I will try with a newly created guest account probably.

Comment: I tried from a different user account. The result is the same. boot2docker start -v produces same output

Comment: @Rajmohan Can you try a reinstallation as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/30059307/6309?

Comment: The steps in the link did not help

Comment: finally it worked after I did the following steps. Donno which step helped. so mentioning everything.

Comment: @Rajmohan then uninstall boot2docker and VirtualBox, reinstall (not in standard path but in simpler path), like I did in http://stackoverflow.com/a/29303930/6309

Comment: uninstalling boot2docker, virtualbox and GIT followed by deleting .ssh, .boot2docker and VirtualBox VMs folders in user directory helped. It works now after reinstall. thanks @VonC for the help.