# VirtualBox VM won't boot

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, virtual

VirtualBox won't boot the VM no matter what...I tryied with Vagrant and Docker.
Vagrant gave me timed out messages and Docker gave me exit code (1). I read tons of suggestions related to this problem but still found no solution. Any suggestion is welcomed.
VirtualBox version: 4.3.26
Vagrant version: 1.7.2
Docker Version: 1.6.0 
and I'm running on windows 8.1

Comment: Have you enabled virtualisation in your bios?

Comment: Have you tried Virtualbox on its own? Maybe using one of the pre-built dev vms, then you at least know Virtualbox works http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html

Comment: Post your vagrant file too just in case there's anything odd in there perhaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by just shutting down the Virtual Box VM network.It set itself up again on NAT when I rebooted the VM, so that was the solution... It's probably a virtualbox bug.

Answer (score 0):

Which OS do you want to use in VirtualBox VM? For me it worked when I downloaded the latest version from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads. I have had troubles with some OS images but as I understand the question you don't even get that far.

Tried the solution in [docker on windows not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26587945/docker-on-windows-not-working) ? It's Windows 7 but might solve your issue.

Comment: no.. I tried bios virtualization and it's on. I am using the latest version of virtualbox, and I'm trying to bring up Ubuntu. I also tried downgrading the virtualbox to older versions.. still not working.

Comment: Okay that sounds strange to me. I hope you get it working and if not you might consider trying http://www.vmware.com/ Make sure that if you have a x86 processor simulation in either virutal machine that you then get the x86 version of Ubuntu.